# Pattern to remove a specific "/Folder/File.Ext" path combination in GIT

Tags: git, pattern-matching

My current GIT branch has some projects, all of them with "Debug" folders inside, that also contain .XML files I don't want to track.

Too late I noticed they all have got into my GIT index, and I want to remove them. I tested the bash command:

```
$ git rm --dry-run --cached "**/bin/Debug/*.xml"
```

But it shows that also undesirable subfolders will be included, as noted here (see **file3.xml**):

```
D:\TestFolder\Project\bin\Debug\file1.xml
D:\TestFolder\Project\bin\Debug\file2.xml
D:\TestFolder\Project\bin\Debug\AnotherFolder\file3.xml     <--- !!!!
D:\TestFolder\Project\bin\Debug\file4.xml
```

Which search pattern will avoid **file3.xml** being included in the remove operation?

Comment: `cd` into the Debug directory and then use `./*.xml` or `./file?.xml`, see what that gives you.

Comment: @PaulHodges Result of query is:
`oscar@LENOVO MINGW32 /d/TestFolder/Project/bin/Debug (Desarrollo)`
`$ ./*.xml` (new line) 
`./file1.xml: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'` (new line) 
`./file1.xml: line 1: '<?xml version="1.0"?>'`

Comment: Sorry Oscar. I meant to try running the same `git rm` as above from the same directory as the file so that you didn't need path info. `git rm --dry-run --cached file1.xml`

Comment: Also, please c.f. http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive - you get much better results if people see that you are actually paying attention.

Comment: The command `git rm --dry-run --cached ./*.xml` also searched recursively in deeper folders, in spite of the '.' prefix. Finally my solution has been deleting *all* .xml cached entries, and used the *.gitignore* file to re-enter the paths I wanted to exclude (in above case, `/D/TestFolder/Project/bin/Debug/AnotherFolder/file3.xml`). Thank you, specially for your kind advise about responsiveness, you are right.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. :)